# Limit of an integral (Arrow theorem)

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Im not sure about a limit of an integral. I would like to prove that there is a solution for this integral for d, and this solution is unique. The integral is:

$$\beta = \int_d^{\infty}(x-d)f(x) dx$$

We know that $0<\beta<\mathbb{E}[X]$, and f(x) is the density function of X. X is a nonnegative random variable, $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$.
I have tried the following:
Let be $g(d) = \int_d^{\infty}(x-d)f(x) dx$.

First lets see $g(0) = ?$. Its easy, i think $g(0) = E[X]$. Next I have showed that $g(d)$ is a monotone decreasing and continous function. Its differentiable, so its continous, and its easy to prove, that its monotone decreasing.

So the last thing to show is 
$$\lim_{d \rightarrow \infty} \int_d^{\infty}(x-d)f(x) dx = -\infty $$
If the limit is $-\infty$, there would be a unique solution for $g(d)$. Unfortunately i cant prove this step. Does anybody have ideas for this problem?

Comment: Hint: For every nonnegative $d$, $$\int_d^{\infty}(x-d)f(x) dx=\int g_d(x)f(x) dx,\qquad g_d:x\mapsto(x-d)\,\mathbf 1_{x>d},$$ and $(g_d)$ is a decreasing family with limit $0$ and uniformly bounded by $g_0:x\mapsto x\,\mathbf 1_{x>0}$. Hence... (But no, the limit is not $-\infty$, note that every $g_d$ is nonnegative everywhere hence every integral is nonnegative.)

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Unfortunately I dont really understand how does this help me showing that there is a unique solution. Can you please explain me?

Comment: Yes, $(g_d)$ is decreasing hence all you have to do is (i) to compute the value of the integral at $d=0$ and its limit when $d\to\infty$, and (ii) to concoct a continuity argument to apply the IVT. This would yield the existence of a solution. For the uniqueness, show that the function is strictly decreasing.

Comment: At d=0 the integral is
$$\int_0^{\infty} x f(x) = \mathbb{E}[X]$$
When $d \rightarrow \infty$ the limit of the integral is 0. Im thinking about the further steps.

Comment: I was thinking: At d=0 the integral is $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$, and the limit is 0, and because of the derivative of this integral is $-f(d)$, its strictly decreasing and continous. But i cant apply the IVT, because the function is always positive. Where is my mistake?